# Как изменить css в конкретном плагине?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

На моем сайте есть плгин курса валют. На сраницах отображается [блок с валютами](https://zagrangid.com/kurs-valyut/usd_gmd)

Есть проблема, возле иконок отображается [странные квадратики](https://skrinshoter.ru/s/300124/FLbruyA1.jpg?download=1&name=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82-30-01-2024%2005:54:23.jpg):

Посмотрев код в инспекторе я нашел что за это отвечает такой вот блок в css

```css
.single ul li {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 22px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 7px 25px;
    position: relative;
}
```

И если удалить position: relative; квадратики изчезают. Но есть проблема, в таком случае они пропадают везде, на других страницах, чего мне не хотелось бы, так как там они выглядят в тему.
Как поправить в этом конкретном случае?

Comment: Это не "странные квадратики", а псевдоэлементы `.single ul li:before`, и они не исчезают после удаления у li `position: relative;`, а начинают позиционироваться относительно body (т.е. улетают в начало документа). Чтобы совсем убрать их на конкретной странице, Вам надо на этой странице родительскому блоку .single задать ещё какой-нибудь класс (например, .not-before) и прописать `.single.not-before ul li:before { display: none }`